# Using wildcards

Tags: sql, wildcard, netezza

Can anyone help me out with this-

There is a column in the database as "TEXT".
This column hold some string value.
I want to search any row that is having '%' in this column .

For eg how will i search for a row having value 'Vivek%123' in the column TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql there is something known as an escape character, basically if you use this character it will be ignored and the character right behind it will be used as a literal instead of a wildcard in the case of %

```
WHERE Text LIKE '%!%%'
ESCAPE '!'
```

The above sql statement will allow you to search for any string containing a percentage character '%' so it could find anything in the format of

> string%string

Comment: and it's alerady been answered because I'm too slow :p

Comment: Can we do the same thing using [%], if yes then how?

Comment: In transact sql the [ ] around the % acts the same as the escape character so the sql would become "LIKE '%[%]%' as for normal sql I don't really know, let me look that up

Comment: square brackets are normally used to get a single character from a list of characters eg. if you say like 'a[bcde]f' you would find everything from 'abf' to 'aef' so I don't really think it is meant to be used this way

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the % character

```
WHERE COL1 LIKE 'Vivek@%123' ESCAPE '@' ;
```